# Simulating random variables from a discrete distribution II

Tags: probability, simulation, random-generation, variable

I have the following discrete probability distribution where $p$, $q$ and $r$  are known constants:

$P(X=0)=q$, $0<q<1$

$P(X=1)=1-p-q-r$, $0<p+q+r<1$

$P(X=2)=p$, $0<p<1$

$P(X=3)=r$, $0<r<1$

How can I sample from this distribution?

Answer (score 2):

To generate $n$ independent values from this distribution, you can use:

```
sample(0:3, size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(p, 1-p-q-r, q, r))
```

For example, here we generate $n=10^6$ values and show the sample proportions:

```
#Generate a large number of values from this distribution
set.seed(1)
p <- 0.11
q <- 0.20
r <- 0.35
n <- 10^6
X <- sample(0:3, size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(p, 1-p-q-r, q, r))

#Show sample proportions
table(X)/n

X
       0        1        2        3 
0.109570 0.340265 0.200222 0.349943
```

Comment: How do you do this in SPSS? You may be able to create an SPSS syntax file with the sps extension.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite simple strategy for discrete distributions such as this with small number of elements in the support:

```
u <- generate a uniform RV in [0,1]
if u < q: x <- 0
elseif u < 1-p-r: x <- 1
elseif u < 1-r: x <- 2
else x <- 3
```

This is basically an over simplification of [Inverse Transform Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling.).

Comment: How do you do this in SPSS? You may be able to create an SPSS syntax file with the sps extension.

Comment: I don't know SPSS. But, it's so simple that you should be able to implement it in almost every language you're familiar with.

Comment: Which programming language did you use?

Comment: My answer is pseudo-code. Ben has written it in R.

Comment: Now I understood. With p = 0.05, q = 0.03 and r = 0.01 in SPSS the syntax is: COMPUTE U=RV.UNIFORM(0,1).
RECODE U (0.0 thru 0.03=0) (0.03 thru 0.94=1) (0.94 thru 0.99=2) (ELSE=3).
EXECUTE.

Comment: @AdvanderVen yes, that seems correct.

Comment: @ gunes Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: @AdvanderVen if you find the answers useful, can you please accept and/or upvote it/them?

Comment: I do not know how to do this.

Comment: @AdvanderVen to accept it, you’ll click the tick under the arrow next to the answer you want to accept. And if you want to upvote it as well, you’ll click the arrow pointing towards upwards which you can do it for any answer.